# What''s the best way to parse the following log entry in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, logging

I'm working on a task that will parse log files. What's the best way to parse the following log string in Java?

```
    EMPLOYER  :   NAME      : Company          ID : 23                   TYPE     : Academy
                 FOUNDED    : 2012-01-05 11:01:18.658                    CATEGORY : College
    EMPLOYEE  :   NAME      :  John                                      TIN      : 123456
                 GENDER     :  Male                                      STATUS   : Prob
    COMMENT   : Data sent to 192.168.0.1:8088
    USER DATA : Any string.
```

I'm particularly concerned with the keywords "Employer" and "Employee" (which I don't need) and the colons that appear in the "Founded" and "Comment" fields (if in case I'll be using the colon as a delimiter).

Thanks!

Comment: Need more details. For example do you have any technologies you are currently using? Does the log contain other text? How much data is involved? The data looks like a fixed format/character position log, is this so?

Comment: What do you need to extract? Are there repeated sections exactly like what you described?

Comment: Hi. I'm interested with the key-value pairs e.g. Name = Company, ID = 23, Type = Academy, and so on. This is an example of one log entry and there are lots of these log entries contained in a text file. I'm going to parse these log files using the Java app I am building right now. And yes, this is a fixed format/character positioning log. Thanks!

Comment: I dont mean to be a prick, but do people think about how to solve it themselves before they post these kind of questions?...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any best way for something like that.  It is clearly an *ad hoc* format with no systematic meta-structure (contrast with XML for example ...)

You could try regexes, but I fear that they'd get too complex.

You could use a parser generator, but that's probably beyond your current capabilities.  (Otherwise you'd have though of this yourself.)

Instead, I'd recommend implement the parser using Java's `Scanner` class.  The problem of context sensitive delimiters can be addressed by *changing the delimiter regex* depending on what you are expecting next, or by using `Scanner.nextLine()` to get the rest of the line irrespective of delimiters.

---

One of the issues with questions like this is that you don't have a well-defined format.  Instead you have just shown us a simple example.  This example may be *typical*, but it doesn't deal with the edge cases.  (You've identified at least one of them already.)  And that also raises the possibility that it is not possible to parse the log file entries without embedding "business knowledge" into the parser; e.g. that dates will always be in a certain format, or that company names never contain a colon.  And if you don't actually know what those rules are (e.g. because they are not properly specified anywhere) then your parser will be fragile.